# Restrict operations to Specific user

Tags: 7, users

I constructed my admin/content page using my custom module

Steps i follow
 1. retrieve data from multiple tables and displayed it in table
 2. I gave edit and Delete options

From admin/user edit and delete options working good

Now my question is i logged in as authenticated user how to disable edit and delete options for admin created pages.Only user will see edit/delete option for his own created pages.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to implement [hook_permissions()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_permission/7). And you probably also need to read up on [user_access()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_access/7). The strategy is to create a permission set, grant it for the admin role, and then check for user_access before you render the buttons. This way the buttons will only show for users who have been granted the permissions.